# JDBCTemplate returns data when debugging but not during normal operation

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Inside a web application, Spring's JdbcTemplate returns an empty list for some simple sql (`SELECT * FROM view_name` -- view_name is a view of one column) where there is known data.

When I use the remote java application debugger with eclipse/tomcat, the query returns the results as expected.

## Java Call

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
results = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from view_name", String.class)
```

I enabled Spring's jdbc logging (level DEBUG) and there is no difference in the output between debugging or normal runs other than results don't return with normal operation. I'm looking for any sort of pointers or other debugging tips to solve this issue.

Comment: Check your datasource configuration in your web project? or if you can post some more config information...,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution was to add a semi-colon to the query (e.g. `select * from view_name;`). I'm guessing that this idiosyncracy is more a function of PostGRES than Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this query using a testcase, and when you normally run through the server you are getting the results?

If that is the case ,  then I think you need to look for the DataSource configuration for the connection pools.

But this is the first time hearing the issue, checking your data source configuration might help.

Comment: No, there was no test case for this call. (I'm modifying/extending someone else's code which worked before, all I changed was the table name).